# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "screen_retriever"

Tags: macos, flutter

I am tried to enable my flutter app to support macOS platform. Now I tried to run my flutter app in macOS(macOS Big sur) using this command in terminal, before this command I have enable the macOS support config and create the macOS config from exists repo:

```
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter run -d macos
```

but the command output from terminal look like this:

```
Changing current working directory to: /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf-dict
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1,226ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `FlutterMacOS` from `Flutter/ephemeral`
    -> Fetching podspec for `audioplayers` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/audioplayers/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `device_info_plus_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/device_info_plus_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `hotkey_manager` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/hotkey_manager/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `package_info_plus_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `screen_retriever` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/screen_retriever/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `screen_text_extractor` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/screen_text_extractor/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `tray_manager` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/tray_manager/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `uni_links_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/uni_links_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_macos` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_macos/macos`
    -> Fetching podspec for `window_manager` from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/window_manager/macos`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_8_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/d/HotKey/0.1.2/HotKey.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in
      repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "screen_retriever":
      In Podfile:
        screen_retriever (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/screen_retriever/macos`)

    Specs satisfying the `screen_retriever (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/screen_retriever/macos`)` dependency were found, but
    they required a higher minimum deployment target.

    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in
    resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in
    `resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in
    resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /Users/dolphin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Exception: Error running pod install
(base)
```

what should I do to avoid this problem and make the app could run in macOS(Intel Processor)? what should I do to make `screen_retriever` compatible with the project? This is my Podfile from platform version:

```
platform :osx, '10.11'
```

the `screen_retriever` was a flutter package, why the pod will use it?

Answer (score 0):

you just needs to perform this commands follow this commands

first you needs to clean the project build in your project directory in ios folder

**flutter clean**

**pod install**   --> it can take suitable pod version for your project

now you can run your app & if till you get error then you can update the pod using

**pod update**